# auto-generate key for hash table in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable, symbols, case-sensitive

I would like to generate sequential keys that I can use across a number of hash tables. I will call them 'id1','id2' etc. If ht is my hash table then I would like to make symbols from strings as keys. To add an entry to the hash table I want to so something like:

```
(setf (gethash (make-symbol "id1") ht) 1)
```

And then access it again with

```
(gethash 'id1 ht)
```

I don't think *make-symbol* is giving me what I want, and the key 'id1' sn't recognised.

What is the best way to make this key?

Comment: You may be leaking symbols. Why not just use strings as keys?

Comment: I was thinking that symbol lookups would be faster than strings. I will do speed comparison. If there is no speed hit then strings would be more simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Error: symbol should be in a package and needs the correct case**

In your case we have:

```
CL-USER 24 > (symbol-name (make-symbol "id0"))
"id0"

CL-USER 25 > (symbol-package (make-symbol "id0"))
NIL
```

Make sure that you think about the following:

- intern the symbol in a package
- intern the symbol in the correct package
- make sure the symbol has the correct name with the correct case
- write symbols with the case you intend to use, possibly you need to escape the symbol to preserve the case

**Examples:**

uppercased symbol and lowercase symbol name -> not eq

```
CL-USER 26 > (eq 'id0 (intern "id0" "CL-USER"))
NIL
```

uppercased symbol and uppercase symbol name -> is eq

```
CL-USER 27 > (eq 'id0 (intern "ID0" "CL-USER"))
T
```

an escaped&lowercase symbol and a lowercase symbol name -> is eq

```
CL-USER 28 > (eq '|id0| (intern "id0" "CL-USER"))
T
```

Answer (score 2):

`make-symbol` creates uninterned symbols. It means you will have a unique symbol every time. To get an interned symbol use [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it still doesn't match the key.

CL-USER> (setf (gethash (intern "id1234") tt) 1234)

CL-USER> (gethash 'id1234 tt)
NIL
NIL

Comment: @DavidWallis depending on the settings of the reader a symbol might be automatically uppercased while a string that is interned is not. Try `(eq (intern "ID1234") 'id1234)`. See [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/23_ab.htm) Also Rainer mentions package. I suggest using the `keyword` package. Then you can compare with `:id1234`